# restkit mapping

Tags: ios, post, mapping, restkit

hey i'm new to iOS and having a hard time with RestKit

can anyone help me on how to do these two post requests

1)post a long value and map the response to

```
@interface CountResultVO : NSObject
{
  long offercount;
  long insertCount;
  long favouriteOfferCount;
  long favouriteInsertCount;
}
```

2)post the above object and map response to

```
@interface FooList : NSObject
{
  NSArray * foo; 
}
```

my main problem is posting payloads of primitive variables like int, long etc instead of mapped objects.

Comment: Hello, can you give us more details ? Why there is two differents interface for CountResultVO ? have you ever code for the mapping ?

Comment: sorry, The classes are quiet large and i shortened them for simplicity to read, didn't realize they had the same name.

Comment: I'm not pretty sure but for numbers Restkit supports NSNumber, you should define your long values as that kind of data. For the array in FooList you need to define which kind of object you are expecting to have in the NSArray.

Comment: Here's a nice explanation https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/restkit-tutorial-how-to-fetch-data-from-an-api-into-core-data-9326af750e10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be useful to you: http://liebke.github.com/restkit-github-client-example/